# VSCode task to run Django server and open Firefox

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, firefox

I'm trying to make a task that runs the Django server and opens Firefox.

I've tried with

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
       {
            "label": "Django Server",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "(python manage.py runserver &); sleep 10 && firefox http://127.0.0.1:8000",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
       }
    ]
}
```

The browser displays "Unable to connect". Refreshing the page doesn't help. Everything works fine if I run `python manage.py runserver` on the command line and then open http://127.0.0.1:8000 in Firefox manually.

*NOTE: everything works as expected when I switch `firefox` for `chromium`* in the `command` field.